# modify back route in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

In my scenario, I am coming from the following route:

```
model/{model}/edit
```

and I am accessing route:

```
model/{model}/duplicate
```

I make a copy of the model and store it

```
$duplicate_model = $model->replicate();
$duplicate_model->save();
```

after that I wish to return back to edit route of the new model by doing something along the lines of this:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('model' => $duplicate_model);
```

hoping that it would replace the model id with that of the duplicated model, but it does not.

I cannot access a specific route, because there are different cases in which the duplicate route may be accessed.

Comment: what do you mean with the back route ? like when the back button is pressed ? because that is not how browsers work.

Comment: I mean the laravel redirect()->back()  method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the solutions is to get resolve to resolve a route name from the back URL like this, provided that all possible back routes are named:

```
$back_route_name = app('router')->getRoutes()->match(app('request')->create(redirect()->back()->getTargetUrl()))->getName();
```

and then redirect to the route by name:

```
return redirect()->route($back_route_name, ['template' => $duplicate_template]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a "path()" in your model.
In this case 
/

> /model/{model}/edit

define a function in your model

> public function path() {
>   return '/model/' . $this->id . '/edit';
>   }

in your ThatModelController.php

simply

> return redirect($dumplicate_model->path());

It should work,Jeffery Way uses this convention.

**Note:** If you are using route model binding and using slug 
  the path() function should return $this->slug instead of $this->id